# Notification from python backend to Android App through Firebase doesn't get to phone

Tags: python, android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I've build an *Android* app that receives notifications from *Firebase* console, but now I would like to make it receive from a Python backend through *Firebase*. So what I actually want to do is to send from python to firebase and from there to phone.

This is what I've coded in python

```py
    import firebase_admin
    from firebase_admin import credentials, messaging

    cred = credentials.Certificate(r'path/to/file')


    default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

    registration_token = "xxx"

    message = messaging.Message(
    notification=messaging.Notification(
        title="This is a notification",
        body="This is sent from python"
    ),
    data={
        'score': '850',
        'time': '2:45',
    },
    token=registration_token
    )

    response = messaging.send(message)

    print("Succesfully sent message", response)
```

I have also generated a file from Firebase a `json` that i added to my project that is in the variable `'cred'`.

When I run the script I get:

`Succesfully sent message projects/test1-80ea2/messages/0:158...`

But nothing appears on the phone from the android studio emulator. Can you please help me how to do this?.

Thanks in advance